# invalid conversion from 'byte*' to 'byte'

Tags: android, c, arduino, adk

**invalid conversion from 'byte*' to 'byte'**

i have write this arduino function

```
byte receiveMessage(AndroidAccessory acc,boolean accstates){
    if(accstates){
        byte rcvmsg[255];
        int len = acc.read(rcvmsg, sizeof(rcvmsg), 1);
        if (len > 0) {
            if (rcvmsg[0] == COMMAND_TEXT) {
                if (rcvmsg[1] == TARGET_DEFAULT){
                byte textLength = rcvmsg[2];
                int textEndIndex = 3 + textLength;
                byte theMessage[textLength];
                int i=0;
                    for(int x = 3; x < textEndIndex; x++) {
                        theMessage[i]=rcvmsg[x];
                        i++;
                        delay(250);
                    }
                return theMessage;
                delay(250);
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

this is the error

```
In function byte receiveMessage(AndroidAccessory, boolean) invalid conversion from byte*' to 'byte"
```

this function  is to receive the data from the android and return it as a byte array

Comment: You can't do this `return theMessage;` because `theMessage` is a local variable, and also `delay(250)` does nothing there.

Comment: there are a few problems: 1) the return statement is returning a 'pointer to byte', but the declared return type is 'byte'  2) the first delay is not needed as you are moving memory to memory.  3) the second delay will never be executed due to the return statement before it.  4) when the function exits, the message[] array is undefined so need to malloc an area and return a pointer to that malloc'd area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dynamic allocation, or pass the array to the function as a parameter which is a better solution in your case

```
void receiveMessage(AndroidAccessory acc, boolean accstates, byte *theMessage){
    if (theMessage == NULL)
        return;
    if(accstates){
        byte rcvmsg[255];
        int len = acc.read(rcvmsg, sizeof(rcvmsg), 1);
        if (len > 0) {
            if (rcvmsg[0] == COMMAND_TEXT) {
                if (rcvmsg[1] == TARGET_DEFAULT){
                byte textLength = rcvmsg[2];
                int textEndIndex = 3 + textLength;
                int i=0;
                    for(int x = 3; x < textEndIndex; x++) {
                        theMessage[i]=rcvmsg[x];
                        i++;
                        delay(250);
                    }
                return;
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

with this, you will call the function passing the array to it, for example

```
byte theMessage[255];

receiveMessage(acc, accstates, theMessage);
/* here the message already contains the data you read in the function */
```

But you can't return a local variable, because the data is only valid in the scope where the variable is valid, in fact it's invalid right outside the `if (rcvmsg[0] == COMMAND_TEXT)` block, because you defined it local to that block.

**Note**: please read **Wimmel**'s comment, or you could set the last byte to `'\0'` if it's just text, and then use the array as a string.

Comment: You probably want to return the length of the message received, so the caller knows if something has been received and how much.

Comment: اhi this line that will receive the message                                                         int len = acc.read(rcvmsg, sizeof(rcvmsg), 1);                                                    i wort this method to receive  it so i cant bass it before ginning it

Answer (score 0):

As far as the error is concerned you are returning the incorrect value.

```
theMessage is a byte array not a byte
```

Also the last answers explains why cant you return local variable pointer